# How to edit the binary file in VS code like the way in notepad++?

Tags: visual-studio-code, binaryfiles, hex-editors

As we know that, the extensions such as "Hex Editor" or "hexdump" in VS code can edit the binary file. However, I do now know how to insert or delete characters, like what I can do in **notepad++**.

For example, in notepad++, when I open the rar file, I can see the beginning characters are "Rar!". I can delete them, then save, then insert "Rar!" at the beginning, then save, then the rar file can be opened as normal. However, I do not find a way to delete or insert characters like the above-mentioned way in VS code.

How can I do that in VS code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This deletion and then re-insertion of the RAR header marker, is that something you do very often? Maybe we should chat about your productivity :-) Just joking, I know that was an example.

Comment: As an aside, this is already entered as a feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-hexeditor/issues/71. You may want to leave a comment there and hopefully it will get some more love.